# How can you tell whether list-initialization calls a std::initializer_list constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization, class-members, stdinitializerlist

My question is about the confusion in C++ default class member initialization between using an initializer list and calling a constructor.

There is no ambiguity in the language but a possible confusion in the developer's mind, leading to obscure bugs. Do you know a good way to detect or avoid this confusion?

When declaring a variable, there is no confusion because using an `initializer_list` and calling a constructor use distinct syntaxes:

```
using block = std::vector<int>;
block a{4, 5};  // brackets => initializer list, 2 elements, with values 4 and 5
block b(4, 5);  // parentheses => constructor call, 4 elements, all with value 5
```

Calling a constructor in a default member initializer uses braces instead of parentheses. However, when the type of the member accepts a `initializer_list`, this becomes confusing:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int size, int value);
};

class C
{
public:
    A     a{4, 5};        // Call constructor A(4, 5)
    block b{4, 5};        // Initializer list, not constructor call, even though same syntax
    block c{block(4, 5)}; // Force a constructor call, but awkward syntax
};
```

The confusion comes from whether the member's type accepts an `initializer_list` or not.

Do you know a nice way to handle this?

Comment: Teach your developers that the `std::initializer_list` form always has preference?

Comment: @Botje, easy to say, but not very helpful: how do you "obviously" know that `std::initializer_list` is a possible option for type `block` but not `A`?

Comment: There is no simple solution to the long-standing dilemma that list initialization could also call `std::initializer_list` constructors. This is especially annoying in templates where you don't know whether such a constructor exists. I'm voting to close this question because the answers are inevitably stylistic recommendations and opinion-based.

Comment: @JanSchultke, don't abruptly close a question just because you find it stylistic. Actual developers may spend a long time to find bugs like this. Having reasonable programming rules or advises would be really helpful for everyone.

Comment: There is no way to tell whether `T{...}` calls a `std::initializer_list` constructor without knowing which constructors `T` has, so the only thing people can give you are stylistic recommendations that mitigate this problem. Stylistic recommendations are opinion-based questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow. I don't make the rules. I agree that such rules/advice can be useful and there's a place for it; but that place is rather [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and not SO.

Comment: A properly configured IDE can tell you about the existence of `std::initializer_list` constructors and that you're calling them.

Comment: The initializer_list constructor is "only" triggered when all the values are of (or convertible to) the value_type involved. For example, `Type x{42, "Hello"};`is not using an inilializer_lst.

Answer (score 3):

In-class member initializers also support `=`:

```
block b = block(4, 5);
```

This is slightly less awkward than `block b{block(4, 5)};`.